# Using references in ASP.NET with Visual Studio and TFS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs

I am working with Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio 2008 for the first time.  I had a web site project that was done with Visual Web Developer Express, which I have converted to a solution containing a Web Application Project, setup for TFS source control, etc etc.

TFS was having issues checking in/uploading some of my referenced DDLs, specifically AjaxControlToolKit, saying things like /bin/AjaxControlToolKit.pdb couldn't be found.  I removed the reference, deleted everything it had in /bin (it had created lots of folders like /ar, /cs, /de, etc etc along with other files like /bin/AjaxControlTookKit.dll), then re-added the reference to AjaxControlToolKit.  It will now upload, and works fine locally, but it didn't re-create anything in /bin.  I have other references that work fine and have info in /bin (ie: /References/LinqKit.dll and /bin/LinqKit.dll)  I cannot do a build on the server yet, but locally it works.  So, will this work when its built on the server?  Why didn't it recreate anything in the /bin folder?  Is that something to do with Visual Web Developer Web Site vs Visual Studio Web Application/Solution?  Any info is appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References are *references*, not copies of the assemblies. Where are the assemblies you're trying to work with?

Typically, you'll want to check in third-party assemblies that you are not maintaining source. You'll then want to change the file references to point to the version from source control.

Of course, this means that all your developers and build machines will need to maintain the same folder structure on disk.